# PHP : Upload de ficheiro

Tags: php, file-upload

Estou aqui com um problema em fazer um *upload* de um ficheiro XML em PHP.

Tenho um formulário que me permite selecionar um ficheiro:

```
<form id="upload" action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input id='uploaded_file' type='file' name='uploaded_file' title="Procurar ficheiro" /> 
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name ="submitA_" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Tenho o código para ler o ficheiro (através do DOM) e importar os dados para a BD:

```
$uploaded  = (object) $_FILES['uploaded_file']; //line 42
$import->dom->load( $uploaded->tmp_name );
$import->updateDB();
```

O que acontece é quando o ficheiro é relativamente grande (9MB), o objeto  `$uploaded->tmp_name` fica vazio e, por consequência, não é feito o *upload* para a BD, segue a baixo o *warning* do PHP:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Empty string supplied as input on line 42

O `$uploaded->error` é `NULL`  e o resultado do `var_dump($uploaded);` é:

> object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }

Nota: No `php.ini` tenho `upload_max_filesize = 128M`  e `max_execution_time = 60`

Comment: Talvez seu problema seja a configuração do PHP, verifique o `upload_max_filesize`, qual o valor que esta configurado?

Comment: Não esse o problema porque tenho o mesmo servidor a fazer upload de ficheiro até 128 MB

Comment: O que você tem em `$uploaded->error`? Se possível mostre o resultado de `var_dump($uploaded);`.

Comment: Verifique o timeout do script se não está "estourando". Pode ser que o problema esteja no tempo do upload, e não no tamanho. http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: A propósito, seria legal um título mais descritivo para o problema, o que acha? (além de estarem sobrando as tags html5, dom e xml). Jaja deleto este comment aqui. Era parte do de cima, mas são dois assuntos separados, e esse aqui é mero "palpite".

Comment: @Bacco Tenho o `max_execution_time = 60` que chega perfeitamente uma vez que nem 20 segundos demora a ler o ficheiro. Um título tipo o que?

Comment: @Vieira já tem o resultado do `var_dump` e do `$uploaded->error` na pergunta.

Comment: Já consegui encontrar o problema: [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15641/7210)
Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na configuração do PHP (`php.ini`):

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

**Se o tamanho dos dados postados for maior do que `post_max_size` então as superglobais `$_POST` e `$_FILES` estão vazias.**

Fica aqui a dica para verificarem quando tiverem problemas de upload de ficheiros em PHP verificar sempre no `php.ini`:

- [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) - *tamanho máximo dos dados postados*
- [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) - *tamanho máximo do ficheiro*
- [memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) - *limite de memória*
- [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) - *limite de tempo de execução*
- [max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) - *limite de tempo de input*

Tendo sempre em conta que, o tamanho do `post_max_size` deverá ser maior que `upload_max_filesize`. Se `memory limit` estiver ativo no seu *script* deverá ser maior do que `post_max_size`.

Baseado na [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/585631/1817673) e na [documentação do PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Answer (score 2):

Inicialmente eu não havia conseguido reproduzir seu erro, com o seu código ligeiramente adaptado. Aqui eu obtive:

> DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Apesar de ser uma mensagem clara do ponto de vista *input/output* não ajuda muito quando o contexto é upload.

De acordo com [esse bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39823) reportado, [DOMDocument::load()](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.load.php) não leva em conta o *include_path* o que requer que o *path* absoluto seja informado, o que não faz qualquer sentido já que o valor dessa entrada de $_FILES já é absoluto.

Por teimosia, passei o valor a ser informado para a DOM por `realpath()`. Mesmo que `realpath`não tenha afetado o dado, isto é, continuou com *path* absoluto correto, consegui reproduzir seu erro. Talvez até porque a DOM force o *cast* para string (`(string) FALSE`) o que gera uma string vazia.

Fui atrás do arquivo temporário e o mesmo não existia (!). Re-enviei o arquivo, e funcionou, mas o arquivo ainda continuava sumido.

Com todos esses problemas, a única solução plausível e até então livre de imprevistos foi voltar ao bê-a-bá de upload de arquivos e REALMENTE fazer o upload do arquivo.

Dado o caso didático em questão, não me preocupei muito com segurança e simplesmente fiz isso:

```
if( $uploaded -> error == ERR_OK ) {

    move_uploaded_file( $uploaded -> tmp_name, './uploaded.xml' );
}
```

E passei o arquivo enviado, aqui nomeado **uploaded.xml**, para o método da DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom -> load( './uploaded.xml' );
```

Comment: O problema é que não posso mesmo guardar no servidor, que o ficheiro depois será enviado para uma *cloud*

Comment: É ainda mais seguro você armazenar no seu servidor e depois mover para o cloud, de repente até na mesma Requisição. Ou então, caso o cloud que você tenha contratado possua alguma espécie de API, pode fazer o upload direto pra ele.

Comment: Sim mas preciso de guardar primeiro na BD. E não posso de forma alguma armazenar no servidor, tem de ser lido na hora.