# Download de arquivo com curl e php

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho dois servidores o **server1** e o **server2**, o **server2** só aceita requisição do **server1** se for outro ip ele retorna 404, o meu site está no **server1** e os arquivos para download no **server2**, fiz o seguinte script para retornar o download do **server2**:

```
    ob_start();
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($url) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($r)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $r;
```

Porém quando o arquivo é muito grande ele exibe a seguinte mensagem erro de memória qual seria a solução para isso?

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 139642559 bytes) in

Comment: Tente aumentar o limite através do comando: `ini_set("memory_limit","512M");`

Comment: @Math a partida isso não é boa prática, se não tiveres um servidor dedicado. Podes consumir os recursos do servidor com o PHP.

Comment: @JorgeB. obrigado pela informação, não sou mt bom em php. Mas e aí? Pelo menos resolve?

Comment: Leandro de qualquer forma dê uma olhada nessa resposta:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15641/7210

Comment: Sim resolve @Math. Mas por exemplo eu tenho um servidor da empresa com apenas 2G de RAM, se eu usar 512 só para o PHP vai deixar os outros serviços a pão e água ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Teria alguma outra forma de retornar o download ?

Comment: Leandro também ando a procura dessa resposta. Até hoje não sei qual a melhor forma de fazer Download e Upload no PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Não** use o PHP para fazer isto, mas sim, use proxy reverso do Apache:

Exemplo de configuração (parte) no **server1**:

```
ProxyPass       /arquivos/  http://server2.example.com/
```

ou ainda você pode trabalhar com tipos de arquivo:

```
<LocationMatch \.pdf$>
  ProxyPass http://server2.example.com/
</Locationmatch>
```

Extra:

Se você precisa do IP ma máquina do cliente, em **server2**, este código lhe ajudará:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP do server1

if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $server)) {
    if (strpos($server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'],',') !== false) {
        $server['REMOTE_ADDR'] = current(explode(',', $server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
    } else {
        $server['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $server['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }

    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $server['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // IP do Cliente
```

Comment: Nessa segundo exemplo tudo que for pdf vai para esse endereço?

Comment: Sim, no segundo exemplo, tudo vai para o server2, mas no server2, o IP do cliente que aparecerá é o IP do Server1. Você precisa do IP da máquina do cliente no server2?

Comment: Não, o request tem que ser com o ip do server1 e só retornar o download para cliente.

Comment: Então isto irá resolver. Se no futuro você precisar aumentar a segurança, implemente regras de bloqueio no server1

Comment: Da para gerar esse ProxyPass no php porque as url são dinâmicas?

Comment: ProxyPass você deve configurar no Apache, e fazer o RELOAD ou RESTART do server Apache a cada alteração, portanto, não, não dá pra gerar no PHP

Comment: @LeandroCosta decidiu o que fará?

Comment: ainda não, estou dando uma estudada para ver o melhor método assim que encontrar posto aqui!

Answer (score 0):

O que esse erro significa é que você está a tentar enviar `bytes` de informação acima do limite configurado que é de `256 Megabytes`.

Experimente adicionar isto no topo do seu código:
`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Ref: [Memory Limit](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Se isso não funcionar, você terá de modificar o seu ficheiro `.htaccess` e aumentar os valores para os parâmetros:
`post_max_size = 100M`
`upload_max_filesize = 100M`

Comment: Mas se o arquivo tiver Gigas?

Comment: @Leandro pode configurar para os valores que quiser, se precisar de passar gigas de informação configure os limites para `2048M`por exemplo, ou mais.

Comment: Mas se duas pessoas fizerem um download de arquivos de 2GB vai dar erro?

Comment: não porque essas restrições são para o tamanho individual de ficheiros e não para a soma total de download em buffer.

Comment: Saquei value cara! :D

Comment: E se duas pessoas ao mesmo tempo baixarem um arquivo de 2048M em um server com 2048M de memória?