# Ajax não enviar imagem para a pasta com o PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Não estou conseguindo enviar a imagem para uma pasta, usando o Ajax e o PHP, o nome do arquivo envia corretamente, é só o arquivo mesmo que não grava na pasta, a pasta já tem permissão chmod 777.

O que preciso fazer no ajax para o PHP poder gravar a imagem na pasta?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_cadastro').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            Nome: {
                required: true,
            },
            SobreNome: {
                required: true,
            }
        },    
    messages: {
        required: "Campo obrigatório",
        remote: "Please fix this field.",
        email: "Por favor insira um email válido",
        url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
        date: "Please enter a valid date.",
        dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
        number: "Por favor digite apenas números.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits.",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format( "Não insira mais do que {0} caracteres." ),
        minlength: $.validator.format( "Digite pelo menos {0} caracteres." ),
        rangelength: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long." ),
        range: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1}." ),
        max: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}." ),
        min: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}." ),
        step: $.validator.format( "Please enter a multiple of {0}." )
    },  
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
 $(".resultado_form_cadastro").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
var form = $('#form_cadastro');


var Logomarca = $('#Logomarca').prop('files')[0];


var form_data = new FormData();



    form_data.append('Logomarca', Logomarca);
    //alert(form_data);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form_cadastro.php',

        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(php_script_response){
            //alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
// pegando os dados

        }

     })            .done(function(data){
                $('.resultado_form_cadastro').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('.resultado_form_cadastro').fadeIn('slow').html(data);

                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
            });
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});
```

Formulário html

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" id="form_cadastro" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="Logomarca">Logomarca</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Logomarca"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="funcionamento">Horário de Funcionamento</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="funcionamento" placeholder="Horário de Funcionamento">
                    </div>
                </div>

</form
```

PHP

```
$file_name_logomarca = $_FILES['logomarca']['name'];
        $file_size_logomarca =$_FILES['logomarca']['size'];
        $file_tmp_logomarca =$_FILES['logomarca']['tmp_name'];
        $file_type_logomarca=$_FILES['logomarca']['type'];  
        if($file_size_logomarca > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';


        $desired_dir="uploads";
        if(empty($errors)==true){

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name_logomarca)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_logomarca,"$desired_dir/".$file_name_logomarca);
            }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name_logomarca.time();
                 rename($file_tmp_logomarca,$new_dir) ;             
            }
            mysql_query($query);            
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
```

Comment: Não é o AJAX que grava é o PHP. Qual código você está usando no back-end (PHP)?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr coloquei o código PHP também na pergunta

Comment: Altere `form_data.append('Logomarca', Logomarca);` para `form_data.append('logomarca', Logomarca);`

Comment: assim não está gravando e tambem nao recebe o nome da imagem.

assim como eu fiz  ele pega o nome e não grava a imagem form_data.append('Logomarca', Logomarca);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema no *JavaScript*

No *PHP*, tanto os nomes de variável, quantos os nomes dos índices são [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity), por isso você deve cuidar dessas diferenças entre maiúscula e minúscula.

Você pode fazer o seguinte teste para confirmar:

```
<?php

$abc = "Valdeir";
$abC = "Valdeir";

$abcd = [
    "Nome"   => "Valdeir",
    "github" => "https://github.com/valdeirpsr"
];

var_dump(
    isset($abc), //true
    isset($ABC), //false
    isset($aBc), //false
    isset($abC), //true

    isset($abcd['nome']),   //false
    isset($abcd['GitHub']), //false
    isset($abcd['Nome']),   //true
    isset($abcd['github'])  //true
);
```

<sup>*Demonstração: https://ideone.com/EpqaPV*</sup>

Portanto, você deve alterar o nome no índice (do `FormData`) para minúsculo (como está no seu *PHP*) ou alterar no seu *PHP* e deixar conforme seu *JavaScript*, por exemplo:

**Primeiro Modo (*JavaScript*):**

```
var Logomarca = $('#Logomarca').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('logomarca', Logomarca);
```

**Segundo Modo (*PHP*):**

```
$file_name_logomarca = $_FILES['Logomarca']['name'];
$file_size_logomarca =$_FILES['Logomarca']['size'];
$file_tmp_logomarca =$_FILES['Logomarca']['tmp_name'];
$file_type_logomarca=$_FILES['Logomarca']['type'];
```

---

### Alternativas

Caso não funcione, deixo duas alternativas:

**1.** Utilize o código abaixo para verificar se há erros com o arquivo enviado.

```
if ($_FILES['Logomarca']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    die( "Código do erro: " . $_FILES['Logomarca']['error'] );
}
```

**2.** As vezes o “upload” não funciona devido as configurações do *PHP*, neste caso é necessário configurar as opções conforme a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15641/99718

---

### Análise e exemplo

Analisando o código e adicionando um exemplo mais completo.

Ao analisar seu código, percebi que o tamanho do “upload” precisa ser — no mínimo — `2097152` bytes (ou `2MB`), porém, esse valor também é informado como o valor máximo.

Ou seja, como seu esse é o valor mínimo e máximo ao mesmo tempo, o “upload” não funcionará devido `if(empty($errors)==true){`, acredito eu, que você esqueceu de fechar essa a condição `if($file_size_logomarca > 2097152){`.

```
<?php

$file_name_logomarca = $_FILES['logomarca']['name'];
$file_size_logomarca = $_FILES['logomarca']['size'];
$file_tmp_logomarca  = $_FILES['logomarca']['tmp_name'];
$file_type_logomarca = $_FILES['logomarca']['type'];

if($file_size_logomarca > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
}

$desired_dir="uploads";

if(empty($errors)==true){

    if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name_logomarca) == false){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_logomarca, "{$desired_dir}/{$file_name_logomarca}");
    }
    else{
        $new_dir="{$desired_dir}/{$file_name_logomarca}".time();        
        rename($file_tmp_logomarca,$new_dir) ;             
    }

}else{
    print_r($errors);
}

if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: fiz com o Primeiro modo e não funcionou para gravar a imagem, só o nome da imagem que pegou. Também não retornou nenhum erro com o código que você enviou

Comment: O php está certinho pois quando eu faço upload sem usar o Ajax, com o PHP direto funciona

Comment: poderia adptar no meu código isso que vc disse? pra ver se funciona!