# Por que eu não consigo fazer o upload maiores que 2mb com esse script?

Tags: php, file-upload

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload"/><br/>
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST"){
    $file = isset($_FILES["fileUpload"])?$_FILES["fileUpload"]:"";
    if($file["error"]){

    }

    $dirUploads = "uploads";
    if(!is_dir($dirUploads)){
        mkdir($dirUploads);
    }
   if (move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dirUploads.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"])){
       echo "upload realizado com sucesso"."<br>";

   }else{
       throw new Exception("Não foi possivel fazer o upload");
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: não dá erro nenhum, simplesmente não envia

Comment: Então aparece a mensagem `upload realizado com sucesso`?

Comment: sim, mas se eu envio um arquivo pequeno envia normal, mas se eu envio um arquivo de uns 3mb simplesmente não vai

Comment: isso no seu computador ou no servidor?

Comment: Essa pergunta resolve o seu problema provavelmente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15573/3635 (resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15641/3635)

Comment: obrigada amigo .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça um arquivo phpinfo.php usando o código abaixo:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

E abra-o no navegador. Na parte "Loaded Configuration File”, aparecerá o caminho para o arquivo de configuração usado, geralmente, php.ini. Claro, se não for hospedagem compartilhada e você tiver acesso a alterá-lo.

Você também poderá criar um arquivo php.ini na raiz do seu projeto.

No php.ini, altere a parte:

**upload_max_filesize:** (tamanho máximo para upload)

**post_max_size:**(tamanho máximo dos dados postados, mas também afeta o upload de arquivos)

**memory_limit:**(quantidade máxima de memória, em bytes, que o script poderá alocar. Isto deve ser maior que do "post_max_size")

**max_execution_time:**(Tempo máximo de execução)

Ao carregar arquivos grandes, é importante não deixar um tempo muito curto, pois poderá ocorrer erros caso não dê tempo de enviar todo o arquivo.

Observe também se o usuário possui acesso para gravar no diretório onde será salvo o arquivo enviado.

Referências:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php

Comment: muito obrigada amigo